How to get the average learning rate for Adam during training?
Adam optimizer has an adaptive learning rate per parameter that is changing during training. I'm trying to get the average learning rate over all parameters. I found this SO question that has a related question, and one of the answers (no accepted answers to this SO question) suggested using
def get_current_lr(optimizer, group_idx, parameter_idx):
    # Adam has different learning rates for each paramter. So we need to pick the
    # group and paramter first.
    group = optimizer.param_groups[group_idx]
    p = group['params'][parameter_idx]

    beta1, _ = group['betas']
    state = optimizer.state[p]

    bias_correction1 = 1 - beta1 ** state['step']
    current_lr = group['lr'] / bias_correction1 / torch.sqrt(state['exp_avg_sq'] + 1e-8)
    return current_lr

I tried to adapt it to my case to get the average, but the results don't make much sense, as the learning rate seems to be ridiculously high (sometimes over 15). So I'm wondering if this is the right approach, or am I missing something.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

torch.manual_seed(42)

def get_current_lr(optimizer):
    # Adam has different learning rates for each paramter. So we need to pick the
    # group and paramter first.
    lrs = []
    for group_idx in range(len(optimizer.param_groups)):
        group = optimizer.param_groups[group_idx]
        for parameter_idx in range(len(opt.param_groups[group_idx]['params'])):
            p = group['params'][parameter_idx]

            beta1, _ = group['betas']
            state = optimizer.state[p]

            bias_correction1 = 1 - beta1 ** state['step']
            current_lr = group['lr'] / bias_correction1 / torch.sqrt(state['exp_avg_sq'] + 1e-8)
            # print(current_lr.mean())
            lrs.append(current_lr.mean().item())

    return sum(lrs)/len(lrs)

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10, 100)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

net = Model()
# opt = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=1e-2)
opt = optim.Adam(net.parameters())

features = torch.rand((100,10))
x_goal = torch.tensor(100)

for epoch in range(100):
    x = net(features)
    loss = torch.square(x_goal - x).mean()
    opt.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
    if epoch % 5 == 0 :
        print(get_current_lr(opt))
>>>
16.065366545983125
3.296213309022278
2.23316600310136
1.8703228593794847
1.7041209160006474
1.6200325103309297
1.5739126955249958
1.5481085549622549
1.5332565682870154
1.5246047580963022
1.5195341832059057
1.5165529197865908
1.5148021120267003
1.5137746352747854
1.5131711492076647
1.512817604085285
1.5126127881085267
1.5124981075282449
1.5124379168978521
1.5124109954704181


Have you also tried with relevant data? There is no constraint as to what the resulting lr value would be since you are averaging over modified learning rates.
